# Display Template HTML file missing in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, display-template

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate display templates on SharePoint. I have a SharePoint online account but I can only see the .js files and not the HTML files we're suppose to work with.

Is this normal for SPO?

Comment: Is this browsing from the Interface or from SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Both. I found the solution. Apparently I need to turn on Publishing Features.

Comment: @Batman If you found a sloution, please post it as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer. It will help others with the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to turn on Publishing Features on your site for the HTML pages to show up, from there you can edit the HMTL files and create new display templates. And yes, this is documented no where.

Comment: For clarity; you must turn on SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure in the Site Collection Features. The corresponding site feature is not required, just the site collection feature.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure you search at the right place for the HTML files:

All Files -> _catalogs -> masterpage -> Display Templates

[Source](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2014/02/19/6-tips-for-using-sharepoint-designer-with-display-templates.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that - I was looking in SPD and couldn't find them at `Portal > Master Pages > Display Templates > Content Web Parts` - then I tried in `_catalogs` and voila!