# Search display template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, display-template

In a previous Sharepoint set-up a created a sub site /search and copied my custom display template in the folder:

> /_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search

[image]

The folder contains HTML and javascript files.

In my new set-up I created a separate site collection for search. The Display template folder now shows only javascript files without HTML files. When I copy my HTML template in this folder it is not converted to javascript.

[image]

How to activate my custom search display template in my new setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate the Publishing feature on site parameters.

Edit : [After lurking](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/display-template-html-file-missing-in-sharepoint-online), it seems that only the Publishing Infrastructure (site collection parameters) is required to display the HTML file.